# FastCGI on Windows (Wordpress): Stopped and Started FastCGI server returns 500

Tags: windows, iis, wordpress, fastcgi

Our wordpress server on windows was having a high CPU usage, so I went into IIS, right-clicked on Fast CGI Setting and clicked "Stop". CPU usage went way down. Yay! But the wordpress site returned 500 error. I Right-clicked it again and clicked "start" and the site is still returning 500. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Restart the server and hope for the best. Otherwise you're going to need to do diagnostics. There's not enough information for anyone to help you, logs are typically useful.

Comment: I received this error when it happened:
`Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: iisfcgi.dll, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b85c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000070d3
Faulting process id: 0x774
Faulting application start time: 0x01d20f82e79d3a12
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisfcgi.dll
Report Id: 43da4cca-7b76-11e6-acd4-0050568e749d`

Comment: What actions have you taken to diagnose the issue? What research have you done into solving the problem yourself?

Comment: I've restared the server and reset IIS.
I've found this link after much research http://forums.iis.net/t/1200936.aspx?w3wp+exe+crash+faulting+module+iisfcgi+dll+
Which tells me this: `Based on the dump, the crash seems to be related to Monitor changes to file setting.  It is checking C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.ini when the issue happening.

 

Action Plan

=======

Please disable Monitor changes to file setting in FastCGI and keep monitor.`

Comment: Update:
I've done some more troubleshooting. I believe stopping and starting FastCGI may have corrupted the php somehow. I've placed a test php file on the wordpress server and it returns a 500, but i've also made a test html file and put it on the server and the page loads fine. Any way besides this to know for sure if the php is corrupt?

Comment: 500 is server error. What do the PHP error logs say?

Comment: Please forgive me i'm not used to PHP. Trying to figure out where to find the php log files.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. If anyone comes across this issue here is what i did:

I used IIS Web Platform Installer to install a newer version of PHP (i did 5.5)

-I opened PHP Manager. Resolved two issues it claimed i had. Opened PHP Info. It told me there was a duplicate line in the config file

-I made a copy of the web.config file. Removed the duplicate line and saved the file.

-I reloaded wordpress in the browser and it was running again.